# How to insert data into a table where a stored procedure is triggered to export a file to the folder of DB Server side

Tags: vba, permissions, export, pgadmin

I want to export data as a file from the table with the stored procedure which was to be triggered when the table was inserted with any data by the SQL of inserting data.

It has worked when I executed some SQL for inserting data with the query tool of the pgAdmin console.  I could see the file exported from the table.

I made VBA code to insert data to that table with ADO.
It worked without the stored procedure to export a file from that table when some data was inserted to that table.

My intention is:

1. Using VBA, insert data into that table
2. The stored procedure triggered to export data as a file from that table

From the console like the pgAdmin query tool, it works.
From the VBA of the Excel file, it wouldn't work with the message that it can create a file for the server.

Without the stored procedure, the VBA inserts data into the table work.
The problem is I need a file.

I guessed the problem is the lack of authority to create a file in a folder of the server.

It didn't work the first time when the console executed the insert query before I gave permission to create a file.

If it were the same reason, I have to know how to give permission to the VBA code or the Excel Application.  Am I right?

Comment: can you share the VBA code?

Comment: I will try to upload the source code.

Answer (score 1):

From the pgadmin4 console, it works fine.
But from the vba, it doesn’t work

[Intention] If tb_img table were inserted with a binary image file, the image file will be exported to the target folder.

— Function I created

Create or Replace function bytea_export()

```
    returns trigger
    language ‘plpgsql’

    as $$
    declare
        l_oid oid;
        r record;
    begin
        l_oid := lo_from_bytea(0, New.f_img);
        perform lo_export(l_oid, ‘D:\IMG\’ || New.f_nm);
        perfor lo_unlink(l_oid);
        return new;
    end;
$$;
```

Alter function bytea_export()
owner to postgres;

grant execute on function bytea_export to postgres;

— Trigger I created

```
Create Trigger trg_img
    after insert or update on tb_img
    for each row
    execute procedure bytea_export();
```

— Table I created

```
Create table tb_img(
      f_nm text
    , f_img bytea
    , f_dwn varchar(1)
);
```

— VBA I created

- It works fine without the trigger above.
- With the trigger, It doesn’t work (message is “The file couldn’t be created to the folder.”)

  Sub Insert_image()
  dim x_path, x_file, binaryData
  x_path = thisworkbook.path & “\IMG”
  x_file = “Test.png”

  ```
    binaryData = readbinaryfile(x_path & “\” & x_file)
    call insertfiletoDB(binaryData, x_file)
  ```

  End sub

  function readbinaryfile(filename)
  const adTypebinary = 1
  dim BinaryStream

  ```
    set BinaryStream = CreateObject(“ADODB.Stream”)
    BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.LoadFromFile filename
    ReadBinaryFile = BinaryStream.Read
  ```

  End function

  Function insertfiletoDB(binarydata, f_nm)
  dim sql, connstr, conndb as ADODB.Connection
  dim rs as ADODB.Recordset

  ```
    sql = “insert into tb_img valeus (‘“
    sql = sql & f_nm & “‘, bytea_import(‘“ & f_nm & “‘))”

    connstr = “DSN=PostgresSQL;Uid=postgres, Pwd= xxxxxxx ;

    set conndb = new adodb.connection
    conndb.open connstr

    set rs = conndb.execute(sql)
    conndb.close
    set conndb = nothing
  ```

  end function